# (JS) resize() + if. Не проверяется условие после каждого изменения размера

Tags: javascript, jquery, условия

Написал скрипт, который должен проверять ширину экрана при каждом изменении размера и совершать действия (пример ниже, пишет в консоль small!!! или BIG!!!).
Беда в том, что из условия берется вариант, корректный на момент **открытия** страницы и дальше его не меняет.

Т.е. открыл я при 900px, начинаю уменьшать, он в логах мне пишет BIG!!!! и корректную ширину (хотя уже меньше 800).

Обновляю страницу, пишет small!!! - увеличиваю, опять же пиксели корректно, а менять фразу не хочет.

Как будто условие проверилось только один раз. Case тоже пробовал.
А может быть из  за того, что resize - от jQuery?
Как сделать, что бы проверялось при каждом изменении размера?

```js
<script>
    var win_width = window.innerWidth;
    $(window).resize(sidebarMoving);


    function sidebarMoving() {
        if (win_width <= 800) {
            console.log('small!!! width: ' + window.innerWidth + 'px')
        } else {
            console.log('BIG!!! width: ' + window.innerWidth + 'px')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ну так win_width не меняется, так как оно скопировано, а не ссылается на window.innerWidth, и равно начальной ширине окна. win_width  замените на window.innerWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что ты *один раз* замерил ширину и сохранил в переменную. После чего подписался на изменение размера, но проверяешь в обработчике *старое* значение.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек! Я понимал что общую логику не улавливаю, потому и не мог даже запрос в гугл составить)
Счастья тебе! Спасибо!